# How to show error messages in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have services and controllers written in AngularJS, in which I am sending a post request to Node.js Application and using send status and code to send a error message like `Username already exists` or`Wrong email and password` but I am not getting How to show these errors in frontend HTML. Like after submit is pressed probably. How would you go about it?

```
$http.post('/register', registerUser).then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data);
}
```

How will I show response .data in the HTML. I read about $error in angular but I don't think it will work in my case as mine is a custom error.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your HTML should be something like:

```
<div ng-if="errorMessage">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
```

Then you can modify `$scope.errorMessage` to display it:

```
$http.post('/register', registerUser).then(function(response){
    switch(response.data) {
        case 'loginExists':
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Username already exists';
            break;
        case 'loginError':
            $scope.errorMessage = 'Wrong email and password';
            break;
        default:
            $scope.errorMessage = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks logically correct. Let me try it. I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use alert with Bootstrap:

```
<div ng-show="hasError">
<alert ng-repeat="error in errors track by $index" type="danger"  close="closeAlert($index)">{{error}}</alert>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.errors = [];
$scope.hasError = false;
$scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
    $scope.errors.splice(index, 1);
}

$http.post('/register', registerUser).then(function(response){
switch(response.data) {
    case 'error1':
        $scope.hasError = true;
        $scope.errors.push('error1');
        break;
    case 'error2':
        $scope.hasError = true;
        $scope.errors.push('error2');
        break;
    default:
        $scope.hasError = true;
        $scope.errors.push("I don't know whats going on");
    }
 }
};
```

You can use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is better like this:

[Message error](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)